# error C2039: 'fabs': is not a member of '`global namespace''

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

My project compiled well, even with full rebuild, then I modified a single parameter in a dialog resource and now it doesn't compile even changing back the parameter, I have many errors, beginning with that:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdlib(24,18): error C2039: 'fabs': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdlib(24,22): error C3861: 'fabs': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdlib(28,18): error C2039: 'fabsf': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdlib(28,23): error C3861: 'fabsf': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdlib(32,18): error C2039: 'fabsl': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdlib(32,23): error C3861: 'fabsl': identifier not found
```

There's also in cmath:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cmath(31,18): error C2039: 'acosf': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cmath(31,23): error C3861: 'acosf': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cmath(35,18): error C2039: 'acoshf': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cmath(35,24): error C3861: 'acoshf': identifier not found
```

As it is in side Microsoft files I don't see what I can do.

EDIT: If I select "go to definition" in cmath, it seems that all these function are not declared because of _CRT_FUNCTIONS_REQUIRED not beeing defined, maybe it can help.

Comment: Do you also have other errors or only this one? Sometimes if you have a simple code issue the compiler won't work and throw a ton of other errors

Comment: I have no error before these, and only in cstdlib and cmath.

Comment: If you are using `<cmath>` functions without `std::` scope, then you should have had errors before this point. If by chance you didn't that doesn't matter. Fix the issue.

Comment: Note: you probably want to use [std::fabs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) rather than the global `::fabs` inherited from C. The C version always takes a `double`, so for `float` and `long double` you'll pay the cost of promotion or truncation. The `std::fabs` version is overloaded for different types though.

Comment: @Entretoize Changing anything in a dialog *resource* does not trigger a recompile of C++ code, so you must have also changed something else elsewhere. Try to find what and where that "*something else*" is.

Comment: The last Visual Studio upgrade changed something relating to what c++ header files include other header files (not sure what exactly). I had to add some new includes to some of my projects to get them to build.

Comment: I don't have any error in my project files and I just modifed a resource and rebuild all manually...  I use "use namespace std" in several files.

Comment: If I select "go to definition" in cmath, it seems that all these function are not declared because of _CRT_FUNCTIONS_REQUIRED not beeing defined, maybe it can help.

Comment: Create a simple project from scratch using `fabs` and tell us what happens.

Comment: I already said the project worked before I modified the resource then a new project with fabs will just work... I found that my resource.h the line `#define _CRT_FUNCTIONS_REQUIRED 0` this caused the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the problem ocured after I modified the resource and I found that `fabs` was not declared because of `_CRT_FUNCTIONS_REQUIRED` not set to 1, I checked my resource.h file (comming from the original project) and saw that many definition lines where set and one containing `#define _CRT_FUNCTIONS_REQUIRED         0`.

I commented out all the lines and uncommented the missing definition, and I was able to compile.